# Duplicate class error on building generate signed apk / bundle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, signed-apk

Im facing this error when trying to generate signed apk / bundle in android-studio. Im using Android Studio Giraffe to build this project.

Event the projects runs in the emulator correctly and Rebuild project is also successful.
My assumption is the some of my dependency is generating duplicate classes but i was not able to find the specific one.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        //classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.1'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
    // Workaround for the following test coverage issue. Remove when fixed:
    // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226070
    configurations.configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.4.201502262128'
            force 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128'
            exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-core-ui"
            exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-compat"
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    project.ext {
        exoplayerPublishEnabled = true
    }
    if (it.hasProperty('externalBuildDir')) {
        if (!new File(externalBuildDir).isAbsolute()) {
            externalBuildDir = new File(rootDir, externalBuildDir)
        }
        buildDir = "${externalBuildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
}

apply from: 'javadoc_combined.gradle'
```

getting this error in build output log

```
> Task :ss-music:checkWithExtensionsReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

Execution failed for task ':ss-music:checkWithExtensionsReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

from your error here i can tell that you have 2 versions of kotlin standard library in included. check if you have added two different versions somewhere

Comment: im not using kotlin dependency.. the project is in java @AkashSinha

Comment: You may not be using it explicitly. Some other dependency might be pulling it in.

Comment: You can run gradle dependencies task. To check what is pulling two versions of kotlin.